# MTM Test runner not detecting of AJAX callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs, visual-studio, playback, mtm

I am doing manual testing and recorded all step in MTM. When run recorded test it get stuck after button click and not proceed to next page. So test get fail.
I face same problem in CUIT and solve the problem with [Ross McNab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849074/jquery-ajax-success-not-getting-triggered-with-coded-ui-test-project/21381319)'s  solution.
I import the same test case in CUI test and run. Test get successful.

I understand what problem arise in CUIT and if same problem happen in manual test case then assume solution is also same but I could not find the place where I can instruct MTM to wait from injecting the javascript to track ajax calls and timers till to get a real XMLHttpRequest, and ajax callbacks will work again..

My application using HTML and AngularJS only.

For any other query please fill free to ask.
Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this is very simple.

Open mtm.exe.config file (I got it in Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE)

Open the file

Place this code in appSettings

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="WebWaitForReadyLevel" value="3"/>
</appSettings>
```

Save and close.

Restart MTM.

Thanks...