# Coded UI tests on IE does not behave similar to the manual test

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

I am running a coded UI test, using the Page Object Pattern, not based on recording. The test is on a web app that uses AngularJS. When I run the test using automation the behavior of some pages is different from the manual testing. For example, some filters are based on date pickers. When I change the date range manually, the angular model is refreshed and the new data is rendered in IE. However, when I do that through automation, no data is refreshed although on developer tools, I can see that the request is sent and data received successfully. I made sure that both the manual IE and the automation one are adjusted to the same document mode, 10. I am running my tests using VS2012/Win8.1 and VS2013/Windows 7 with all updates.

I appreciate your help,

Ahmed

Comment: Does adding delay help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about **AngularJS** but it seems like there's and issue with XMLHttpRequest object which is used by Coded UI for tracking

Same issue was  there with JQuery where Coded UI is not able to get Ajax success message to refresh the data. You can try below solution in my case it worked like charm.

[Jquery AJAX success not getting triggered with Coded UI test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849074/jquery-ajax-success-not-getting-triggered-with-coded-ui-test-project)

Comment: @AhmedAwad mark this as a answer. which will help others too.. :)