# Loading Frame Hangs During Automated Coded UI Test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using a recorded action via coded ui tests in Visual Studio 2013 to launch an internal website and log in. All of this processes normally, except after logging in a loading animation continues to spin until the test fails. Attempting to log in normally without the automated test works flawlessly and the page loads normally with a <2 second delay.

I have attempted to add a pause in but no matter how long I wait it does not load. Is there a reason the coded ui test would be causing the page to hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce509aa3-cb60-4596-b1ff-1ea11242d981/coded-ui-automation-issue-with-vs2013?forum=vstest) explains the problem using a much more simple application and points to this answer here on SO:

[Jquery AJAX success not getting triggered with Coded UI test project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849074/jquery-ajax-success-not-getting-triggered-with-coded-ui-test-project/21381319)

And if you do not have an app.config file, just right-click your solution->Add->New Item->Application configuration file and then replace existing text with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebWaitForReadyLevel" value="3"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```